# 3D effect button hover state CSS (Possible bug?)

Tags: css, button, 3d, hover, mouseover

Just wondered if any one had any experience with fixing an issue i have using 3D effect hover states for buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/andeh/b47xor6d/

```
.button{
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
line-height: 44px;
height: 44px;
width: 159px;
background: #ff9600;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
color: #fff;
}
.button:hover {
display: block;
min-height: 44px;
min-width: 159px;
background: #e68700;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
border: 0 solid #fff;
color: #fff;
position: relative;
top: -5px;
bottom: auto;
left: -5px;
right: auto;
cursor: pointer;
background: #e68700;
box-shadow: #c2c2c2 1px 1px, #c2c2c2 2px 2px, #c2c2c2 3px 3px, #c2c2c2 4px 4px, #c2c2c2 5px 5px;
}
```

As you can see in my example, what the problem is, is that when you hover over the button, if your cursor is on the shadow, then the hover state will deactivate.
I understand that this is because i'm essentially moving the button away from the cursor, but i thought that the shadow created could some how retain the hover state?

If any one knows of any fixes that would be great! but at the minute its just an irritant more than anything.

Thanks!

Andy

Comment: you're using a box shadow for the effect. a SHADOW. i.e. that's like saying 'here, are you standing on me?' while someone is stood on your shadow.

Comment: @jbutler483 you have a different approach that is widely compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a different approach, just set the `box-shadow` to be `inset`, so the shadow will be inside the button and you will not loose hover state when hovering on shadow.

Also you will need to add more specific `border-radius` on hover so it looks like an outer shadow.. see this http://jsfiddle.net/b47xor6d/3/

```
.button:hover {
    display: block;
    min-height: 44px;
    height:49px;
     width: 164px;
    min-width: 159px;
    background: #e68700;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 0 solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    top: -5px;
    bottom: auto;
     left: -5px;
    right: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #e68700;
    box-shadow:inset #c2c2c2 -1px -1px,inset #c2c2c2 -2px -2px,inset #c2c2c2 -3px -3px,inset #c2c2c2  -4px -4px,inset #c2c2c2 -5px -5px;
}
```

Comment: inset! so simple... i knew there would be a simple solution! thanks

Answer (score 1):

```css
.button{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    line-height: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    width: 159px;
    background: #ff9600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: transform .3s ease,box-shadow .3s ease
}
.button:hover {
    transform: translate3d(-5px,-5px,0);
    box-shadow: #c2c2c2 1px 1px, #c2c2c2 2px 2px, #c2c2c2 3px 3px, #c2c2c2 4px 4px, #c2c2c2 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="button">button</span>
```

Or try :speudo-elements

```css
.button{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 44px;
    width: 159px;
    color: transparent
}
.button:after{
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 44px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ff9600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: transform .3s ease,box-shadow .3s ease
}
.button:hover:after {
    transform: translate3d(-5px,-5px,0);
    box-shadow: #c2c2c2 1px 1px, #c2c2c2 2px 2px, #c2c2c2 3px 3px, #c2c2c2 4px 4px, #c2c2c2 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="button" data-text=button>button</span>
```

Comment: the first one still has the same issue regarding the mouse over on shadow, however the 2nd issue is a very nice and elegant button indeed! which i will stash for future cases, but unfortunately the browser compatibility just isn't there for the translate3d yet. Until i can convince my company to scrap support for IE8, its just not an option :( though defo stored for other projects! its a lovely bit of transition though!